# How to get OneDrive to start automatically on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS server w/o GUI?

Tags: server

How do you get OneDrive to start automatically on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS server without GUI?

I have tried creating the a script in the /etc/init.d/ folder but that hasn't worked.

Comment: Please use `systemd` for that!

Comment: I believe Ubuntu has a GUI Tool (Startup Applications) for this purpose and supports command line commands